# Confusion with method call from IRB in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I was playing with method definition and calling to them in the `main` of IRB.

```
def show
 p "hi"
end
#=> nil

show
#"hi"
#=> "hi"

self.show
#"hi"
#=> "hi"
```

The above are good and understood.

Now let's try something different:

```
def Foo
 p "hi"
end
#=> nil

Foo
#NameError: uninitialized constant Foo
        #from (irb):4
        #from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

While the call to `Foo` has thrown an error as above,how does the below remove that?

```
self.Foo
#"hi"
#=> "hi"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby, you can call methods without a receiver and without an argument list. However, this means that there is an ambiguity: does `foo` mean "call method `foo` on the implicit receiver `self` without arguments, i.e. equivalent to `self.foo()`" or does it mean "dereference the variable `foo`"? Ruby can't know which you mean, so there are some simple rules.

For a local variable, the rule is that `foo` is *always* a method call, unless `foo` is *statically known at parse time* to be a local variable. So, when is it statically known to be a variable? When there was an assignment to that variable which was *parsed* (but not necessarily executed!) before the use.

Example:

```
foo        # method call

if false
  foo = 42 # will never be executed, but *will* be parsed
end

foo        # variable dereference, since the `foo` assignment was parsed
```

For constant variables, the rule is even simpler: `Foo` is *always* interpreted as a constant dereference. Period.

So, how do you call a method with such a name? Easy: like I said, the ambiguity arises only for method calls with no argument list and no explicit receiver. So, if we add either one or both of those, Ruby will know that we are trying to call a method and not dereference a variable:

```
foo()
self.foo
self.foo()

Foo()
self.Foo
self.Foo()
```

Of course, in the example you gave above, only the first one will work. When you define a method at the top-level, it is added as a `private` method to `Object`, and `private` methods can only be called *without* an explicit receiver, even if that receiver is `self`. So, `self.Foo` won't work, because `Foo` is private. (Except in IRb, where, for convenience reasons, top-level methods are `public`.)

Comment: Humm.. you are absolutely right here is another test - `>> x = 10
=> 10
>> def x
>> p "hi"
>> end
=> nil
>> eval(:x.id2name)
=> 10`